# how to use facebook connect plugin in phonegap correctly

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

assume I have a phonegap app that has a custom login system that works with a php backend. Assume my login screen has a text input for the username which is an email and a password input. Under those I have 2 buttons. My Login button (which works fine) and a button that says Login with facebook that is defined like this

```
<label class="item-input">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive" id="fblogin" onclick="fblogin()">Login with Facebook</button>
            </label>
```

now for javascript i have

```
<script> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                                //set page title using settings 
                document.getElementById("page_title").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("login_index_page_title");
                        setTimeout(function(){
                function fblogin(){

                var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
}

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
    fbLoginSuccess,
    function (error) { alert("" + error) }
);
            }
            }, 1000);

});
      </script>
```

This is suppose to be based on https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin
example. I am sure I made a mistake in the code. My facebook app is setup fine. My app id is also set and all that. I am sure I made a mistake. The idea is that assuming someone succeeds in logging in i will so of my own logic to connect the user to my system if he/she doesn't already exist

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the error handler or than some syntax errors. Issue resolved example referenced works fine